How to Compute the Derivative of Maximum Drawdown (MDD) with Respect to Portfolio Weights
I am working on a financial model and need to calculate the derivative of Maximum Drawdown (MDD) with respect to the portfolio weight vector (assume we fix it at the beginning and keep unchanged). The portfolio consists of $n$ assets, each with a constant weight over all time steps. The daily returns for these assets are given by $\mathbf{r}(t) = (r_1(t), r_2(t), \ldots, r_n(t))$.
Definitions:

Portfolio Value $V(t)$:
$$ V(t) = \mathbf{w}^T (\mathbf{1} + \mathbf{r}(t)) $$
Where:

$\mathbf{w} = (w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_n)$ is the portfolio weight vector,
$\mathbf{1}$ is a vector of ones.


Maximum Drawdown (MDD) Formula:
$$ \text{MDD}_T = \max_{t \in [0, T]} \left( \frac{\mathbf{w}^T (\mathbf{1} + \mathbf{r}(t)) - \max_{0 \leq s \leq t} \mathbf{w}^T (\mathbf{1} + \mathbf{r}(s))}{\mathbf{w}^T (\mathbf{1} + \mathbf{r}(t))} \right) $$


Question:
I am trying to compute the derivative of MDD with respect to the portfolio weight vector $\mathbf{w}$:
$$ \frac{\partial \text{MDD}_T}{\partial \mathbf{w}} $$
Given the complexity introduced by the maximum function and the dependence on $\mathbf{w}$, I am unsure how to proceed with this differentiation.
Handling the Maximum Function: How does one differentiate through the maximum function in this context?
Any guidance, references, or detailed steps on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
